# Update one list of dictionaries with the values of another list of dictionaries if they have the same specific value

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

For example we have 2 lists of dictionaries

```
a = [{'fruit_id':234, 'type':'apple', 'color':'red'}]
b = [{'fruit_id':235, 'type':'kiwi', 'color':'brown'},{'fruit_id':234, 'type':'apple', 'color':'green'}]
```

I want to update list A with list B if they have the same fruit_id, so for this example list A will have the color value changed to green. What is a good algorithm for this?

Comment: a = [{'fruit_id:234, 'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}] Your syntax is incorrect. Maybe  a = [{'fruit_id:234':{'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}}] is what  you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of dictionaries is expensive for computations in pure Python. I recommend you use a 3rd party library, such as Pandas, for vectorised functionality. Here's an example:

```
a = [{'fruit_id':234, 'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}]

b = [{'fruit_id':235, 'type': 'kiwi', 'color': 'brown'},
     {'fruit_id':234, 'type': 'apple', 'color': 'green'}]

import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index('fruit_id')
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b).set_index('fruit_id')

df_a.update(df_b)

res = df_a.reset_index().to_dict('records')

print(res)

[{'fruit_id': 234, 'color': 'green', 'type': 'apple'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{'fruit_id':234, 'type':'apple', 'color':'red'}]
b = [{'fruit_id':235, 'type':'kiwi', 'color':'brown'},{'fruit_id':234, 'type':'apple', 'color':'green'}]

for fruit1 in b:
    for fruit2 in a:
        if fruit1['fruit_id'] == fruit2['fruit_id']:
            fruit2['color'] = fruit1['color']

print a # --> [{'color': 'green', 'type': 'apple', 'fruit_id': 234}]
```

You can loop through both lists to achieve it.